# What is a factory function in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, factory

In an article I read about factory functions in jQuery, but I cannot find anything about that on the internet. What are they and what do they do?

Comment: In jQuery, the `jQuery()` function itself - also represented by `$()` - is a factory function because it is a function that creates new objects.

Comment: Could you post a link to the article you are reading?

Answer (score 10):

Factory functions generally return new objects without requiring you to *explicitly* create them with the `new` keyword.

`$.Deferred()` is a factory function that creates new [`Deferred` objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). `$.when()` creates `promise` objects (a type of object related to Deferredes).

But if you take a step back, `$()` is a factory function *itself* - it creates new jQuery objects. Some of the other jQuery API functions are factories as well, namely when they create new jQuery objects (for example, all [*traversal* type functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) are factories in jQuery, but others, too).

The main purpose in jQuery is that you can keep up the "fluent interface" style of programming:

```
   $("body").css("color", "red").find("a").show().parent().addClass("foo");
//-^-----------------------------^----------------^------------------------
```

Here `^` marks the factories.

Comment: Great explanation and example. Should be the top answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not expert but what ever i know factory method is same as $(document).ready() . basically you can pass $() to run the function after page load.
    as $(function(){
    });
it is same as $(document).ready(function(){});

Answer (score 1):

Its a creational design pattern. You ask for a object with given parameter as input and function will return a return one of several families of related objects/functions.

Ex.

```
function car(name, color,speed) {
var obj = new Object();
//now you can create custom object as per requirement
obj.name = name;
obj.color = color;
obj.speed = speed;

    obj.customFunc = function(){
        console.log("Car name : " + this.name );
    }
    return obj;
}

var customCar = car("carName","red","100kmph");

//log: carName
customCar.customFunc()
```

Answer (score 1):

In the context of JavaScript, the factory pattern is useful when creating browser-compatible objects at run time. For example, the XHR object is created by calling "new XMLHttpRequest()" in Firefox, Chrome, and IE 7+, but in older versions of IE, this object is created via an ActiveX object, even though the objects all share the same set of Level 1 AJAX methods. A wrapper function can be written, e.g. the xmlHTTPRequestObject function in the [Nano AJAX library](http://www.antradar.com/docs-nano-ajax-manual) detects the object availability **at run time**, and instantiate the correct object accordingly. Such wrapper function is considered to be a "factory function".

In jQuery, most of the factory functions are not returning different objects based on browser. However, the end user doesn't have to pick an implementation-specific object. For example, a "car rental factory" will get you a rental car. There's no guarantee which make or model the car will be. Even the **only** make in the jQuery rental company is called, say, "J1", they still don't want you to name the specific car. This allows the library to switch to a different implementation, say "J2" in the future. The factory pattern hides the information about "how it is done", and yet provides a uniform interface for the user to express "what is needed".

Answer (score 0):

> In object-oriented programming, a factory is an object for creating
>   other objects – formally a factory is simply an object that returns an
>   object from some method call, which is assumed to be "new".

from Wikipedia

Answer (score 0):

It's a design pattern.

> Also known as Virtual Constructor, the Factory Method is related to
>   the idea on which libraries work: a library uses abstract classes for
>   defining and maintaining relations between objects. One type of
>   responsibility is creating such objects. The library knows when an
>   object needs to be created, but not what kind of object it should
>   create, this being specific to the application using the library.
>
> The Factory method works just the same way: it defines an interface
>   for creating an object, but leaves the choice of its type to the
>   subclasses, creation being deferred at run-time. A simple real life
>   example of the Factory Method is the hotel. When staying in a hotel
>   you first have to check in. The person working at the front desk will
>   give you a key to your room after you've paid for the room you want
>   and this way he can be looked at as a room  factory. While staying at
>   the hotel, you might need to make a phone call, so you call the front
>   desk and the person there will connect you with the number you need,
>   becoming a phone-call factory, because he controls the access to
>   calls, too.

(Source: http://www.oodesign.com/factory-method-pattern.html)

This [link](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method) is also good information on the Factory Method.